Count results with sync.Map.Range(), vscode prompts copylock issue
I'm trying to count the number of entries in sync.Map, I created a function
func SyncMapSize(data sync.Map) (count int) {
    data.Range(func(key, value interface{}) bool {
        count++
        return true
    })

    return count
}

However, vscode prompts me with SyncMapSize passes lock by value: sync.Map contains sync.Mutex, also a link on copylock: https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/copylocks
However this link is broken, and I don't understand the issues here.
Anyone knows?

The issue is quite simple actually, sync.Map contains a sync.Mutex as a private field and copying mutexes by value is a bad practice in Go, leading to all sorts of data races and corruptions. To fix it, simply change the method signature to take the sync.Map as a pointer
func SyncMapSize(data *sync.Map) (count int) {
    data.Range(func(key, value interface{}) bool {
        count++
        return true
    })
    return count
}

The rule also applies to other types in sync package as well, namely  sync.Cond, sync.RWMutex, sync.Once, sync.Pool and sync.WaitGroup.

It’s not “bad practice” which implies that it might still work somehow, it’s simply incorrect —  it can’t work if you copy a value that needs to be shared.
